# use php-java bridge only to connect to DB

Tags: java, php, database, php-java-bridge

I would like to know how can I use php-java bridge but only to connect to database ..and then i would like to use PHP to view data from DB, to update data from DB and to delete data from DB through PHP files(interface)

Answer (score 0):

What Database are you using?

If you use MySQL, SQLite or MongoDB, there is no need for a bridge since Java can connect to all of them directly. To connect to MySQL (for example) you would use [JDBC](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/).

Comment: I'm using different type of database, like MySQL, ORACLE, ACCESS, PostgreSQL. My web application is all in PHP and i want to use PHP-Java Bridge to connect to different type of DB and to use queries (READ, UPDATE, DELETE etc....). So in "background" I should have java file(s) who will allow me to connect to DB and retrieve informations and show them with PHP files. Any sugestions are welcome !

Comment: If you have to use Java to connect to the Database (and PHP can't connect to it directly) why don't you use JSP at all?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it using Zend Server Community Edition - it has a java bridge option that I am currently using.

However...I have a different opinion on how to get to your destination thast will be faster and easier. To have the ability to switch out databases or use multiple databases is easy in php - use pdo, and you'll be able to keep it generic. You can even connect to MSSQL if you wanted to - it's all there. With PDO prepared statements (your queries) you'll also have similiar security without creating an additional database layer.

Please note: If you already have Java code already written to server as a model, however, rock out!